# add new regions and call block in that region in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to add a view block in a new custom region that I had made in drupal 7

Here is what I am doing:

```
    1. regions[grid_first] = 'Grid First' in theme.info file
    2.  <?php if ($page['grid_first']): ?>
            <div id="grid_first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
              <?php print render($page['grid_first']); ?>
            </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#grid_first -->
          <?php endif; ?>

this code in page.tpl.php inside my theme folder to call the block in this region
```

But I am not able to view my block. Where Iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From Structure > Blocks you can assign any block to your region. The blocks created through views will also be available there.

If you don't see your region displayed there, try clearing cache.

Comment: Have you assigned your block from admin into the 'grid_first' region?